# PhpStorm: Different import path

Tags: javascript, import, phpstorm, webstorm, package.json

In my JS-Project, I have a package.json in every directory to import for example like this:

```
import CustomTextComponent from "@components/TextComponent"
```

instead of

```
import CustomTextComponent from "../../../components/TextComponent"
```

Now, PhpStorm marks every import red but everything runs fine. Where can I set another import path that PhpStorm not only checks node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

are you using [React native hack](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1#.u53b9sdnm) for specifying absolute paths? It had never been supported. If you miss this feature, please follow [WEB-23221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221) for updates.
You can try creating a dummy webpack config like it's suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221#focus=streamItem-27-2719626.0-0 and specifying a path to it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** as a workaround